# Variable not staying set

Tags: php, variables

This is most likely just a PHP problem, and it's probably a pretty simple answer, but I just can't seem to get my brain to function this morning. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 $job_file = $cfs->get('job_file'); // job_file is a URL

 if ($job_file = NULL) {
     echo "NOT AVAILABLE";
 } else {
     echo '<a href="'. $job_file . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
 }
```

It will display the URL of the current page instead of the `$job_file` variable. What am I missing?

Comment: I am betting on @t-f's answer but on the off chance that that isn't it, what is `$cfs` and how is the data saved?

Comment: t-f was correct. Pretty silly of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this **is** PHP...

```
if ($job_file == NULL) {
    ...
```

You might want to compare, and not set, right?

Comment: See, I knew it was something simple I was forgetting... Thanks.